# Как обновить один элемент ListView(ListBox) а не всю коллекцию

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В общем код Xaml на элемент ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Episode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Completion}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel Base

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Property Changed Event Handler        

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion Property Changed Event Handler
}
```

RootViewModel

```
public class RootViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public class Video_Progress
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Completion { get; set; }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Video_Progress> m_Episode;
    public ObservableCollection<Video_Progress> Episode
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Episode;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Episode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Episode));

        }
    }
}
```

Собственно приложение выглядит вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С некоторой периодичностю я записываю данные в LocalBD о позиции видео.
И потом его считываю, чтобы динамически отображались данные ProgressBar на каком месте остановился. И вызываю метод:

```
public void List_Box_Episode()
    {
        var ViewModel = App.ViewModel as RootViewModel;
        double com = 0;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            episode = new ObservableCollection<Video_Progress>();

            foreach (var pars in playlist_balancer.Translator[id_translate].Seasons[id_season].Episode)
            {
                com = LocalDB.Video_Completion();
                com = Math.Round(com);
                episode.Add(new Video_Progress { Title = pars.nubmer_episode, Completion = com });
            }

            ViewModel.Episode = episode;
        });
```

В принципе все работает, все показывает, но есть небольшая проблема, это решение хорошее, только в случае если нужно обновить всю коллекцию. Поскольку, чем больше коллекция, тем больше он ее загружает.

Вот как сделать так, чтоб обновлялась не вся коллекция, а только выбранный элемент? Конкретно ProgressBar?

Comment: НУ, вроде, просто — не создавайте новую ObservableCollection, а берите существующую и правьте в ней элементы. Возможно, для того, чтобы выбрать нужный элемент для изменения, вам потребуется некий идентификатор в вашем `Video_Progress`, ну и да, `Video_Progress` должен реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` для своих свойств, чтобы изменения сразу подхватывались UI

Comment: @Андрей NOP Вроде все просто, но можно бы примерчик, как это реализовать? ")

Comment: К сожалению, нету времени писать полноценный ответ. 1) Добавляете `INotifyPropertyChanged` к `Video_Progress`. 2) Убираете создание новой `ObservableCollection` 3) В вашем цикле `foreach` вместо `episode.Add` пишете логику для поиска нужного `Video_Progress` в существующей коллекции (для этого надо ID какой-то, наверное) 4) Если нашли — просто обновляем свойства у него, если нет — добавляем или *вставляем* в нужную позицию коллекции. Ну и 5) так как вы делаете это всё в отдельном потоке, то саму запись свойств лучше перенаправить в поток UI с помощью диспетчера

Comment: @Андрей NOP Благодарю, твой совет очень помог, всю ночь сидел пытался разобраться, но мне даже не пришлось на класс Video_Progress вешать INotifyPropertyChanged. Просто изменял коллекцию из Dispatcher не создавая новый экземпляр. Видать ViewModel сам видит изменение.

Comment: Оформите решение ответом, чтобы топик не висел открытым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась путем изменения списка. Не надо было создавать новый экземпляр ObservableCollection. А просто его изменить. С учетом того, что список не изменяется в потоке отличном от Dispatcher. Меняем элемент списка по индексу в основном потоке.

```
    public void List_Box_Episode_test()
    {
        var view = App.ViewModel as RootViewModel;

        int ep = view.now_Episode;
        var ep_n = view.now_Balancer;

        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => episode[ep] = new Video_Progress { Completion = view.new_Position, Title = ep_n.nubmer_episode });
    }
```

Comment: Ага, INPC в вашем случае не нужно, т. к. вы не меняете свойства у существующего элемента, а просто создаёте новый. Ну если это вам подходит — отлично.